# App receives SIGABRT on every second run

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios6

I'm experiencing that applications do crash on the Simulator every second time I run them. They receive an abort signal for some reason (See attached screenshot). It has been started recently, but I'm not sure if it's related to upgrading 10.8.4.

[image]

I've just created a new project based on the 'Single View Application' template to make sure it's not something related to my code and it's still crashing.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a known bug in 10.8.4 (http://www.tuaw.com/2013/06/05/devjuice-10-8-4-and-the-ios-simulator/).

> Update your scheme by selecting Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and choose the GDB debugger for your debug scheme.

Comment: omg, i thought this was caused by the beta 5 of xcode i installed (right after updating the OS). this was driving me insane! thanks!

Comment: +1, Thanks a lot! I had the same issues, was driving me insane!